# Microsoft Photo Viewer/Printer (photo print size selection) equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: printing, gimp, photo

When on Windows, I used the default Windows Photo Viewer a lot because it is so easy to print full page images (cropped or not cropped), to any paper size.

Is there a Linux app that can do this as efficiently?

1. Open the image
2. Select paper size
3. Fit to page/Full page option
4. (bonus: crop to fit or not option)

This is what happens if I try to print 11x17 in GIMP, even if I've set the image size to 11x17 (which is an extra step I don't have to do using Windows Image Viewer).  It STILL doesn't' print 11x17!

Here' the print preview:

[image]

Comment: If you mean ubuntu, I guess gimp is suited for your needs.
If other linux distros, may refer to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) for related answers.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this easily with GIMP.

Comment: @WafieAli GIMP is completely cross-platform - it can be used in any Linux distro as well as other systems. But I wouldn't recommend it for this specification

Comment: Have a look here [Alternative image viewers](//askubuntu.com/q/295702) ?

Comment: @Zanna thanks for share with me. I'm still new to Linux distro (Ubuntu). Keen to learn more from  these great communities.

Comment: I use GIMP all the time, but it can't easily do what I am looking for in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Ubuntu repositories you will find a program called Photoprint